# Pandas extract text notation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, using it for a class, and I can't for the life of me find a resource that shows the notation used in pandas when representing text in the extract function. For example:

```
    movies['year'] = movies['title'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True)
```

I know this is telling the extract function to extract everything inside the parentheses from examples done in class, but I don't understand which symbols mean what inside the extract function. Is there a resource that can explain what these symbols mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**In General**

The string argument of the `.str.extract` is a [Regular Expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) (regex), which is a language used for pattern matching and feature extraction in strings. If you go to the section called "Regular Expression Patterns" in the previous link you can find the meaning of the special control characters.

**This Example**

What specifically that regex string means is:
match any character, `.`, zero or more times, `*`, until a parenthesis, `\(`, then extract all the content in the parentheses, `(.*)`, then close parenthesis, `\)`, then any character zero or more times, `.*`, again.

Essentially this will match any string like: `'xxx(message)xxxx'` or `'(message)'` or `'xx(message)'` or `'(message)x'` and extract the `'message'`.

**Notes on Pandas and Regex**

An important part of regular expressions (in general, but particularly for use in pandas with `.str.extract`) is capturing groups. You can 'capture' or grab part of a string by enclosing the pattern for that part inside of parenthesis. Note that these are the unescaped (no preceding slash - the inner set) parentheses in the regex and not the actual parentheses that appear in the string itself, e.g. in `'xxx(message)xxx'`.

Check out the docs on `.str.extract` for a few examples of using regex with capturing groups in pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html